# How to create a new folder on FreeNAS AFP share (create/copy file is working)

Tags: freenas, afp

I set up a FreeNAS 11.2 system with an AFP share with all the default values. I did successfully copy a file from my macOS 10.14.4 machine. What did not work was to create or copy a folder to that share.

What is going on here?

Comment: There is a little + next to the shared folder when I `ls` via `ssh`. Is this some extended attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Update: for some reason my pool was set to `Windows` even though I initially set it to `Mac` and never changed that setting manually. I guess this happened during some update. After resetting it to `Mac` folder creation worked again. I hope nothing got damaged or lost during that process.